# RESTful Responses to PUT/POST

Tags: java, rest, response, put, restful-architecture

Is it RESTful to return a slightly different object, like the one which was send to the server, on a POST/PUT?

Example:

The client sends (POST/PUT) an `Order` to the Server to create an Order. The Server sends a Response Object, lets call it `OrderResponse` which contains the Attributes of the created `Order` plus some different informations like delivery time, terms of payment and so on. Is this RESTful or should i just return an OrderId and offer a new Service, where the Client could retrieve the `OrderResponse`?

**Edit:**

I am not able to give the Client an URL to the new Order, because the Order isnt saved in a Database. My application sends the Order via Messaging to a third party system, where I cant read it from, but the third party system sends me some additonal informations, which I add to the `OrderResponse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not consider `Order` and `OrderResponse` to be different Resources. They are of the same type. It is just that the client can't and shouldn't know all the details of this Resource. The exact ID is assigned by the server, for example.

- Use the same Resource with perhaps different Representations.
- Return a `Location` header in the HTTP response to the `POST` request that contains the URI of the creates `Order`.
- Make the Representation of the `Order` and this URI more complete that the one `POST`ed by the client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you think it is ok to send an `OrderResponse` to the client, when posted an `Order`? Doesnt it mind, that the XML-Tags maybe look like `<OrderResponse>` instead of `<Order>`? See also my edit above!

Comment: In REST there is no such thing as an `OrderResponse`, there is only an `Order`.

Comment: I know, but I am about to expose a SOAP Service also as REST Service and would like to use the same Objects and Business Functions like used in SOAP, so therefore I am struggling with those stuff.

Comment: REST has no business functions, it is about Resources and Representations. Read http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow for a nice introduction to REST.